# How to get firebase document data from CardView in Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

this is the first app i'm making and i still need to learn a lot, so feel free to also correct me on the existing code.

The app i'm making is an administrative kind of app, where you can add, edit and delete orders and such. I can already add orders, and display them im cardViews in a recyclerView, but what i want to do now is be able to click on one of the cards to go to that specific order and be able to update/delete it and for that i'd need the firebase document id and i dont know how to retrieve that from the cardView. If there is code that's necessary that i didnt include please let me know.
*(the app is in dutch so excuse some dutch terms)*

*List code*

```
private const val TAG = "KlantList"
class KlantList : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var firestoreDb: FirebaseFirestore
private lateinit var klant: MutableList<Klanten>
private lateinit var adapter: KlantAdapter

private fun onItemClickHandler(position:Int){
    val intent = Intent(this, DetailScreen::class.java);
    startActivity(intent)
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_klant_list)


    //data source
    klant = mutableListOf()
    //adapter
    adapter = KlantAdapter(this, klant, this::onItemClickHandler)
    //bind adapter and layout manager to the RV
    rvKlant.adapter = adapter
    rvKlant.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

    firestoreDb = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val klantReference = firestoreDb.collection("Orders")
        .orderBy("Name", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
    klantReference.addSnapshotListener{ snapshot, exeption ->
        if (exeption != null || snapshot == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exeption when querying klant", exeption)
            return@addSnapshotListener
        }
        val documents = snapshot.documents
        val klantList = snapshot.toObjects(Klanten::class.java)
        klant.clear()
        klant.addAll(klantList)
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        for (klant in klantList) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Klant ${klant}")
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

*List adapter*

```
class KlantAdapter (val context: Context, val klant: List<Klanten>, val itemClickHandler: (Int) -> Unit) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<KlantAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.example_item, parent, false)
    val headerViewHolder = ViewHolder(view)
    view.setOnClickListener {
        itemClickHandler.invoke(headerViewHolder.adapterPosition)
    }
    return ViewHolder(view)

}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(klant[position])
}

override fun getItemCount() = klant.size

inner class  ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    fun bind(klanten: Klanten) {
        itemView.tvName.text = klanten.Name
        itemView.tvEmail.text = klanten.Leverancier
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share your Klanten class

Comment: Just pass that `id` to the other view that you want.

Comment: There's no such thing as "getting the ID from the card view". If you haven't stored it yourself then you can't get it. A view has no concept of anything other than itself.

Comment: By `view`, I meant fragment or activity. You have a list of `CardView`s and want to open their detail in another `fragment` or `activity` and then update that info. Am I right?

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @MohammadZarei exactly, in the cardview i only display the name thats in the document, when i click on the card i want to go to a new activity and display all teh info in the document and be able to update the info or delete the document.

Comment: @MohammadZarei Right now i'm using the auto generated id by firebase, can i just use that id or do i need to include that in the document?

Comment: @AlexMamo I don't have any errors but i have an actio i want to do and i can't find how i can do this, someone else pointed my problem out clearer than i did, I have a list of CardViews and want to open their detail in another fragment or activity and then update that info.